# How to design schematic with infinite life expectancy

Tags: circuit-design, reliability, code-design

Well I know there is nothing infinite and every device can break on some circumstances.

But still, how to design electronic devices that to be able to function continuously for very long time.

Lets assume the device is relatively complex, containing analog and digital circuits and some programmable unit - CPU for complex data processing.

The technology issues are out of the scope of my question - PCBs, soldering materials, corrosion, etc.

But for example, the limited life of the electrolytic capacitors is ontopic.

What is the maximal life time (estimation of course) with the contemporary element base?

What design solutions we should use and what to avoid?

What can be done by the software, that runs on that system for increasing the life time of the system?

Comment: I promise to give you a design with infinite life expectancy if you promise never to turn it on

Comment: Many manufacturers are busy with opposite question these days - how to make devices which break after specific operating period so that consumer goes buying another device. In regard to your question - each component in its datasheet has nominal life time given device uses it within component's spec.

Comment: @JonRB - In order to avoid this kind of design, I have wrote: "to be able to **function** continuously"

Comment: The title asks about designing a schematic, the but question is about designing a circuit.  Make up your mind.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Well this is probably english language problem. I am not native speaker and for me circuit == schematic. A drawing on a piece of paper (the screen of the computer) with elements and their interconnections, values, etc... Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: A schematic is a drawing, and a circuit is a bunch of electronic parts wired together. A schematic represents or describes the circuit, but isn't the circuit. "Schematic" and "circuit" are most definitely not the same thing. Blueprints aren't houses, and maps aren't land either.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - IMO, the design of the circuit contains a  schematic by definition. So, I am asking about the design of some circuit and this design contains some schematic that defines what elements are used and the topology of the element interconnection. So, this is what I am asking for. Of course, the life time of the device highly depends on many other aspects (for example the materials used), but in this question I am asking only the first, theoretical part of the design.

Comment: Decisions like these are all about balance.  What are you balancing against long lifespan?  For example, does the circuit need to function? What does it do?  The way you design an analog circuit for longevity is *very* different than how you design a digital circuit for longevity because the parameters you need to concern yourself with are so very different.  Another feature is cost.  If you're willing to pay 100x as much, you can get much better lifespan out of your circuit.

Comment: Also, is this unattended-but-operating lifespan, attended-operation lifespan, or shelf-life?  Are you allowed to power cycle, or does it have to be up all the time?  The number of variants to this topic are endless.

Answer (score 8):

> how to design electronic devices that to be able to function
>   continuously for very long time

For MTBF estimations of most modern components in various applications from ground benign to fired off in a missile read [MIL-HDBK-217F Notice 2](https://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/MIL-STD/MIL-HDBK-217F-Notice2.pdf)

> Lets assume the device is relatively complex, containing analog and
>   digital circuits and some programmable unit - CPU for complex data
>   processing

MIL-HDBK-217F guides you in how to determine the overall MTBF of complex electronic circuits.

> The technology issues are out of the scope of my question - PCBs,
>   soldering materials, corrosion, etc.

I don't see why they should be - MIL-HDBK-217F does provide guidance on estimating the MTBF of PCBs

> But for example, the limited life of the electrolytic capacitors is
>   ontopic

And covered in MIL-HDBK-217F

> What is the maximal life time (estimation of course) with the
>   contemporary element base?

Read MIL-HDBK-217F

> What design solutions we should use and what to avoid?

Read MIL-HDBK-217F

> What can be done by the software?

What software?

So, for an RM category resistor (see section 9.1) you would use MIL-HDBK-217F Notice 2 and make a table like this: -

[image]

For a typical SMD capacitor (category CDR) you would do this: -

[image]

And, for a power rectifier running at high temperature you might make this: -

[image]

Comment: "What software?" - The software executed on the programmable unit of the designed device, of course.

Comment: You could have meant the software used to design the schematic i.e. a sim tool, of course!

Comment: Yes, about the software  I will edit the question. Also, your answer seems to be how to compute the MTBF of some already designed circuit. My question is about the reverse - how to design a circuit with maximal MTBF. And I don't think that there is an easy algorithm to convert the first to the second (NP-complete)

Comment: My answer is all about using real life collected data (as embodied in MIL-HDBK-217F) to compare the best scenarios against the worst scenarios of usage, environment and stress. I use the handbook to search for preferred scenarios that can achieve best MTBF and, the handbook leads me to choose the tech that is most appropriate. Of course it can be used retrospectively too.

Comment: @johnfound The first step to achieving maximum MTBF is to understand what effects drive MTBF, and adapt around them.  This is also important because the "best way to design a circuit" varies *greatly* from circuit to circuit, but the principles on how to *quantify* the effects of your choices on MTBF are more more general.

Answer (score 2):

Often the limited lifetime of a component is caused by stress. Avoid stress on the components and the chances that it will last longer will increase (but there is no guarantee !).

Some components are more sensitive to stress than others, the electrolytic capacitors you mention are a good example. We all know that if these have to operate at a high temperature (that's stress), their lifetime will decrease. So keeping things cool will help.

In semiconductors (discrete and chips) electron migration is an issue. High current densities and high temperatures increase this form of stress. Most semiconductor designs are a compromise between cost and lifetime. Often 10,000 or 100,000 hours operation at an elevated temperature is guaranteed. The expected lifetime does increase dramatically at non-elevated temperatures though so again: keeping things cool will help.

In software you could disable (parts of) the device as much as possible. You could optimize the software such that the device never dissipates more than a certain amount of power or let it operate at a lower clock speed when temperatures get too high.

Answer (score 1):

There is too many details to take into account when designing a long-life product.

Apart from the MIL-HDBK-217F which is useful for components' MTBF but not much on derating and long-term characteristics changes (aging).

If you want a fully functional product on long period you'll need to take into account, for instance, capacitors' value change over time which is higher with Y5V dielectric than with X7R.

Also as you can't have the best components at every time you're producing, you'll have to do some screening and burn-in test as in aerospace industry where plane's computers are stressed in temperature, vibration and thermal shock, which help to prevent bad computers from being shipped to customer.

This is the bathtub curve phenomenom, you can read more about it on [wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve).

Also some hints I learned by working in aerospace and automotive industries:

- **SMD or TH components over BGA**

BGA or equivalent component are more prone to soldering mechanical failures due to thermal and mechanical stress. Underfill and adhesive pastes can be used to reduce the stress on these components.

- **Old technologies are more reliable** (related to die process size)

Finer process are more sensible and requires lower voltage with very low noise, which can be difficult to maintain over time. Also newer technologies need some time to have an efficient production with high quality.

Another aspect is that older components are more bug-free than recent ones. Hardware issues have been fixed in design. That's why space and aerospace product use old processor as it is difficult to change the processor when your board is flying to Mars.

Finally, the thinner the die process, the steeper the rise times which could lead to signal integrity issues even with "low frequency" signals, for instance overshoots that could wear out components on the long term.

- **Flash memory is not infinite**

Flash memory has specified maximum writing cycles and data retention time. So software should be aware and carefully write into flash memories. NOR flash can achieve guaranteed 1 millions writing cycles and 20 years data retention. But capacities are smaller than with NAND flash.

Also, a technique seen in aerospace, as the processor was using intensively NOR flash during when powered-up (but it was only powered-up during some specific phases), was software chose one of the two flash chips alternatively (or randomly) at start-up, thus you are mitigating writing cycles issues with data retention.

- **PCB and soldering issues**

Some other phenomenom that should be taken into account are appereance of whiskers with unleaded solder. A [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_(metallurgy)) to give you a hint of this effect. Aerospace is still using leaded solder due to this phenomenom.

Another effect, more seen in automotive is CAF (Conductive Anodic Filament) which is an electromigration effect inside PCB dielectrics that creates a copper filament and conducts to short circuits. This is more relevant with high potential differences and high currents. IPC have layout rules about this and CAF resistant materials also exist.

Comment: +1 mentioning FLASH memories. But 20 years data retention seems to be very short period. Is this means we should provide some reflashing from time to time or this is the whole life of the FLASH memories?

Comment: Data retention of 20 years is normally guaranteed, so most of parts will do more. Data retention is the time when data are kept in memory and can be read for sure. After data retention time bit voltage level will change and you may have some change of bit value (normally a 1 becomes a 0). So data retention means that you have to rewrite same data every 20 years, this is not a short period when NAND flash only do 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that designing robust and long-lifetime circuits is as much about component selection (and screening, etc.) as it is about circuit design. And it has really nothing to do with "schematic".  The schematic diagram only shows how parts are interconnected. It rarely says anything about the source, quality, grade, etc. of the components.  That is more typically found in the bill of materials, etc.

There are certain branches of electronics that specialize in high-reliability design. Two for example are circuits designed for satellites in outer-space. Where we expect decades of operation in some of the most harsh environment. And medical electronics, particularly for implanted devices (pacemakers, etc.)

But even in those examples, satellites are designed with redundancy and remote-control re-configurability, etc.  And pacemakers and other implanted electronic devices have some finite life expectancy before they must be replaced.

Comment: I am not fully agree. Yes, the design of the long-lifetime device is versatile process, but IMHO the carefully designed schematic is very important and this question is exactly about this. Also, notice that "high-reliable" does not necessary means "long-lasting". For example, the missile electronics is very high-reliable, but probably will not work after centuries, because is not designed this way.

Comment: You still do not understand the difference between CIRCUIT and SCHEMATIC.  You can have a perfect circuit even if there is no schematic at all.  And you can have the most beautiful schematic in the universe, but the circuit is a complete failure.

Comment: You can't have "perfect" circuit without perfect schematic first. Or your standard of perfection is very low. So, the schematic is the first step. That is what I am asking in the question - about the first step in the design. I will ask about the other steps in other questions. Or not - considering the low quality of the answers.

Comment: Of course you can have a perfect circuit without a perfect schematic. Many circuits are developed by pragmatic experimentation and then documented with a schematic. And many more use just one or two critical stages sketched on the back of a restaurant napkin.  You obsession with "schematic" is just baffling.

Comment: The "perfect" schematic can exists on various carriers. Including back of a restaurant napkin (Come on, do you ever tried to draw something on the back of a restaurant napkin! And what actually is the **back** of a restaurant napkin???) and even in the someones mind. :P